# Order by query using specific column or alphabetical. - Coldfuison

Tags: sql, coldfusion, sql-order-by

we have a coldfusion website that retrieves our categories then displays them alphabetically.

We would like to be able to force an order by manually arranging the categories with a 'sort' column with a number in but if this number is equal to 0 or null use alphabetical order.

so at the moment the query is

```
<cfquery name="qGetThrdCat" datasource="#request.dsn#">
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_prdtthrdcats, tbl_scnd_thrdcat_rel
    WHERE tbl_scnd_thrdcat_rel.thrdctgry_ID = tbl_prdtthrdcats.thrdctgry_ID
    AND tbl_scnd_thrdcat_rel.scndctgry_ID = #URL.secondary#
    AND thrdctgry_archive = 0
    ORDER BY thrdctgry_Name ASC
</cfquery>
```

It works if I try

```
ORDER BY thrdctgry_Sort ASC
```

but I can't for the life of me join them up, mainly down to my lack of programmer skills.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to sort by `thrdctgry_Sort` but if it is zero or null then you want to sort by `thrdctgry_Name`?

Comment: exactly so if we expressly set a sort order it will follow a number place, for anything else it will be alphabetical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but you should be able to just sort on both columns:

```
ORDER BY thrdctgry_Sort ASC, thrdctgry_Name ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your query with join:

```
select *
from tbl_prdtthrdcats p
join tbl_scnd_thrdcat_rel s
    on p.thrdctgry_ID = s.thrdctgry_ID
where
    s.scndctgry_ID = #URL.secondary# 
and thrdctgry_archive = 0
```

For the sorting, you can use CASE in your ORDER clause.

```
order by
case
    when isnull(thrdctgry_Sort, 0) = 0
    then thrdctgry_Name
    else thrdctgry_Sort
end asc
```

To be honest, I couldn't understand your sorting order completely, but you can play around with it more.

Comment: Hi Muhammed, thankyou for your help. I had a 404 after I made those changes though, here is the query in full -:<cfquery name="qGetThrdCat" datasource="#request.dsn#">
select *
from tbl_prdtthrdcats p
join tbl_scnd_thrdcat_rel s
    on p.thrdctgry_ID = s.thrdctgry_ID
where
    s.scndctgry_ID = #URL.secondary# 
and thrdctgry_archive = 0
order by
case
    when isnull(thrdctgry_Sort, 0) = 0
    then thrdctgry_Name
    else thrdctgry_Sort
end asc

</cfquery>

Comment: Do you mean an HTTP error 404? Can you check this query in your SQL database? What database engine you are using?

Comment: Thanks Muhammed but I tried this in the databse and it didn't work, it may be my limited programming knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfquery name="qGetThrdCat" datasource="#request.dsn#">
SELECT *
FROM tbl_prdtthrdcats, tbl_scnd_thrdcat_rel
WHERE tbl_scnd_thrdcat_rel.thrdctgry_ID = tbl_prdtthrdcats.thrdctgry_ID
AND tbl_scnd_thrdcat_rel.scndctgry_ID = #URL.secondary#
AND thrdctgry_archive = 0
<cfif isNumeric(thrdctgry_Sort) and thrdctgry_Sort GT 0>
ORDER BY thrdctgry_Sort
<cfelse>
ORDER BY thrdctgry_Name ASC
</cfif>
```

Using SQL is the best option, but if Muhammad Ghazi's solution doesn't work this should do the trick using your server-side code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the cfif query just caused a 404 error